# Nativescript: button with icon and multiline title

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I would like to achieve the button look exactly like on the following picture:

[image]

Here is XML for the button I'm using:

```
<Button class="footer-button" loaded="onLoad" textWrap="true">
    <FormattedString>
        <Span id="icon" class="footer-button-icon"/>
        <Span id="text" class="footer-button-text"/>
    </FormattedString>
</Button>
```

Here is the sass styles:

```
.footer-button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: $colorAccent;
    height: 40;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 14;
    margin: 16 0;
    padding: 0 10;

    .footer-button-icon {
        @include fontIcons;
            font-size: 18;
        }
        .footer-button-text {
            @include fontMainText;
        }
    }    
}
```

The result I get:

[image]

I know I can get what I want by crafting a custom view (for ex. 2 labels inside grid-layout), but I would like to know whether it's achievable with button and formatted string or by adjusting native ios and android button properties.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it's impossible because button in NativeScript only accepts text or formatted strings and you can only apply a style on text like color or font (font size, etc.) and no text position, margin, etc.

For your solution, it's better to have a new component with the behaviour of a button

Bootstrap did that on a  with CSS class .btn, so with Angular for example, you make an Angular component.